# in unit test, verify function called with argument NSData (with a NSString in it)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock v3](http://ocmock.org/reference/) do unit testing, I want to test a very simple function named `processInfo:` , its implementation is showing below:

```
@implementation MyService
-(void) processInfo{
  // get info file path
  NSString *infoFilePath = [self getInfoFile];
  // read info data from infoFile
  NSData *infoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:infoFilePath];

  // call another function to handle info data
  [self handleData:infoData];
}

-(void) handleData:(NSData*) infoData {
   ...
}

@end
```

As you see, the `processInfo:` function gets info file path & read data out then call `handleData:(NSData*)` function. Pretty simple logic.

I tried to test the above simple function in following way:

```
-(void) testProcessInfo{
  // create dummy info string
  NSString* dummyInfoStr = @"dummy info";
  // convert above NSString to NSData object
  NSData* dummyInfoData = [dummyInfoStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  // get the same info file path
  NSString* infoFilePath=[self getInfoFile];
  // write dummy info data to info file
  [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

  // CALL function under test
  [myServicePartialMock processInfo];

  // I want to verify that handleData:(NSData*) has been invoked with a NSData argument which contains dummy string @"dummy info"
  // BUT it failed, even though the real implementation does it.
  // For some reason the dummyInfoData is not considered equal to the NSData used in real implementation, though they both contain string @"dummy info"
  OCMVerify([myServicePartialMock handleData:dummyInfoData]);
}
```

I want to verify that function `handleData:(NSData*)` is called with a `NSData` argument which contains dummy string `@"dummy info"`, but it failed, even though the real implementation **did** invoke `handleData:(NSData*)` with a `NSData` object read from file which **does** contain `NSString` of `@"dummy info"`.

I mean looks like `OCMVerify()` **just simply can not verify it**, is it because the `dummyInfoData` is not read from file?

How can I test the `handleData:(NSData*)` is called with a `NSData` type argument that contains dummy string `@"dummy info"` then?

Answer (score 1):

NSData is designed to encapsulate data in a large variety of formats from a variety of sources, so two NSData objects which have identical behaviour are not likely to be actually identical. In this case, the test instance is probably retaining a copy of the NSString, and the implementation instance is probably retaining a file handle, at least until it's used.

In this case, you probably want to use `checkWithBlock:` on `OCMArg` and once there you can check the class and content. You should compare strings rather than their NSData representations, so compare `dummyInfoStr` and `[[NSString alloc] initWithData: infoData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

Comment: thanks, I am not sure how to use checkWithBlock, do you have a code example?

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow just lost my comment, and I'm not going to type it again. I found that reference in the OCMock docs, which suggests that you can use `OCMVerify` with `[OCMArg checkwithBlock:]`. When you're writing the block, you use the method signature given in the docs (i.e., the arg should be `id value`) and then check the type `[value isKindOf: "NSData"]`, cast to NSData `NSData *infoData = value`, build a string as I indicated previously, then check `[infoString isEqualTo: dummyInfoStr]`.